# Can I change Vuetify's outlined textfield label position and line interval?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, textfield

I'm using Vuetify trying to approach [this](https://prnt.sc/226kl82) textfield style. I'm using [outlined textfield provided them](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#outlined) with a simple custom style, but I can't change its label position. Is there any way I could change the label position and the "interval" where the line starts and ends?

I was trying searching in their documentation and found [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#sass) session, but no luck while changing $text-field-outlined-label-position-x or $text-field-outlined-label-position-y.

edit: [this](https://prnt.sc/226nu4o) is the best I could reach, which is actually the default outlined textfield with rounded borders.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<v-text rounded=rounded-lg> <v-text/>`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself.

We can change the margins on the Vuetify classes of v-text-field to change its position. Just change it by your own margin and everything works!

```
.v-text-field__slot {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.v-input__slot > fieldset > legend {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Edit: my answer is outdated nowadays. There are better ways to round stuff in Vuetify